# How to get file input from a text file in java and then display it using an array lists?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

When I run my program that is getting file input from a text file and then saving this input into an array lists, I cannot print the information. I will attach my Student class which is the type I am using for my array lists. I also will attach the class that contains main. I will include a screenshot of the text file and the output that I am currently getting. My goal is to save each students information into a student object and then put these objects into an array lists. Then display the contents of the array lists.
Below is the student class.

```
public class Student {
      public String Name;
      public int BirthYear;
      public int BirthMonth;
      public int BirthDay;
      public double GPA;

      
       public Student(String Name,int BirthYear, int BirthMonth, int BirthDay,double GPA)
       {
          Name = this.Name;
          BirthYear = this.BirthYear;
          BirthMonth =this.BirthMonth;
          BirthDay=this.BirthDay;
          GPA=this.GPA;
       }
    
    public int Age() {
           Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
           if(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)>BirthMonth) {
               return (c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-BirthYear);
           }
           else if(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)<BirthMonth) {
               return (c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-BirthYear)-1;
           }
           else if(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)==BirthMonth) {
               if(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)>BirthDay) {
                   return(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-BirthYear)-1;
               }
               else {
                   return(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-BirthYear);  
               }
           }
           else {
               return 0; 
           }
       }
}
```

Below is the main class

```
    public class RunStudent {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File inputFile = new File("studentData1");
        Scanner FileIn = new Scanner(inputFile);
        ArrayList<Student> List = new ArrayList<Student>();
        
        FileIn.nextLine();
        while(FileIn.hasNextLine()) {
            String FName, LName;
            FName = FileIn.next();
            LName = FileIn.next();
            int BirthYear = FileIn.nextInt();
            int BirthMonth = FileIn.nextInt();
            int BirthDay = FileIn.nextInt();
            double GPA = FileIn.nextDouble();
            String name = FName + " " + LName;
            Student s = new Student(name, BirthYear, BirthMonth, BirthDay, GPA);
            List.add(s);
        }
        FileIn.close();
        for(int i=0; i<List.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Name:" + List.get(i).Name);
            System.out.println("Age:" + List.get(i).Age());
            System.out.println("GPA: " + List.get(i).GPA);
        }

    }

}
```

[This is the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtRT9.png)
[This is a sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyZih.png)

I also have imported java.util.* and java.io.* but it won't let me include it in the post.

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: Also, you should read [Java Code Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html#367).

Answer (score 2):

> *"... I would like to display the students names, Age and GPA"*

The reason the *Student* class is not retaining the information you're provided is due to the code within the *constructor method*.

You are assigning the fields incorrectly.
The *[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)* keyword refers to the class instance context, and not the scope context.

```java
Name = this.Name;
BirthYear = this.BirthYear;
BirthMonth =this.BirthMonth;
BirthDay=this.BirthDay;
GPA=this.GPA;
```

Flip these assignments.

```java
this.Name = Name;
this.BirthYear = BirthYear;
this.BirthMonth = BirthMonth;
this.BirthDay = BirthDay;
this.GPA = GPA;
```

Output

```
Name:David King
Age:18
GPA: 3.211
Name:Jane Hall
Age:21
GPA: 3.9662
Name:Mary Reed
Age:19
GPA: 2.8
Name:John Diaz
Age:20
GPA: 2.916
```

Here are some recommendations for your code.

You can obtain a year value by simply subtracting the *Calendar* values.

```java
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int y = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
return y < 0 ? 0 : y - BirthYear;
```

Or, use a *[Period](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html)* object.

```java
LocalDate bd = LocalDate.of(BirthYear, BirthMonth, BirthDay);
Period p = Period.between(LocalDate.now(), bd);
return Math.max(p.getYears(), 0);
```

Store your *fractional* values—i.e., GPA—as *String* or *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* objects.

Additionally, I would use a *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* on each line over a *Scanner#next* call.

```java
String[] s;
int y, m, d;

FileIn.nextLine();
while(FileIn.hasNextLine()) {
    s = FileIn.nextLine().split(" +");
    y = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
    m = Integer.parseInt(s[3]);
    d = Integer.parseInt(s[4]);
    List.add(new Student(s[0] + ' ' + s[1], y, m, d, s[5]));
}
```